# How to create a Spring Bean of a Inner class?

Tags: java, spring

I would like to create a Spring Bean of a Inner class. If I have the following inner class `B`:

```
package x.y.z;

public class A {
    public class B { }
}
```

I would like to create bean instance in my XML configuration files.

```
<bean class="x.y.z.A.B" name="innerBean" />
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You cannot access your public static inner class with the dot (`.`) notation, instead, use the currency (`$`). An example:

```
<bean class="x.y.z.A$B" name="innerBean" />
```

This will work.

Comment: Also you must define your inner class static, if you plan to instanciate it using Spring.

Comment: Is there any way that do not explicit define inner bean in xml, like @RequestMapping construct it's form bean parameter?