# Spring MVC instantiate inner class form bean property

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

I have post data like:

```
cond[startData]:2015-09-22
cond[endDate]:2015-09-23
cond[orderId]:
```

And my ajax is:

```
cond={
   startDate: "2015-09-22",
   endDate: "2015-09-23",
   orderId: ""
}
queryData = {cond:cond};
$.ajax({
    url: "orderDetail",
    type: "post",
    dataType:"json",
    data: queryData,
    success: function(data){

    }
});
```

And my spring form bean is

```
public class OrderFormBean {
     private Cond cond;
     private Result result;

     // query condition
     public class Cond {
         private String startDate;
         private String endDate;
         private String orderId;
     }

     // query result
     public class Result {
         private String orderId;
         private String orderDate;
         private String operator;
         ...
     }
     ...
 }
```

So, it will cause error:

`org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property 'cond' of bean class [*.OrderFormBean]: Could not instantiate property type [*.OrderFormBean$Cond] to auto-grow nested property path: java.lang.InstantiationException: *.OrderFormBean$Cond`

---

### Edit

I found that even if I post data this way:

```
queryData = {
    "cond.startDate": startDate,
    "cond.endDate": endDate,
    "cond.balanceType": balanceType,
    "cond.orderId": orderId
};
```

Spring still produces the error `Could not instantiate property type [*.OrderFormBean$Cond]`.

*If I move inner class Cond outside, the Spring MVC works.*

So It's the inner class reason, that Spring can't instantiate it.

According to this 
[How to create a Spring Bean of a Inner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886526/how-to-create-a-spring-bean-of-a-inner-class), there is a xml configure. But I don't want to configure it, as `OrderFormBean` is not configured.

Comment: "If I move inner class Cond outside, the sping mvc works." I had this problem before, not exactly in this situation but close. Changing your declarations to "public static class Result" and "public static class Cond" should work for you. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I just edited my answer to solve your problem

Comment: Why downvote this post? I think I try my best to make this question clear. And I really try to figure it out by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is caused by the field `result` being null.

Try the following:

```
 cond={
    startDate: "2015-09-22",
    endDate: "2015-09-23",
    orderId: ""
 };

 result={
    /*whatever you are going to write here*/
 };

 queryData = {
    cond: cond,
    result: result
 };
```

reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/NullValueInNestedPathException.html

EDIT:

Also, your inner classes cannot be instantiated because **non-static inner** classes don't have a **default (no-arguments) constructor**.

Solutions are: either mark your inner classes as `static` or move them outside your "containing" class (to their own separate `.java` files)

For more details you can read: 
http://thecodersbreakfast.net/index.php?post/2011/09/26/Inner-classes-and-the-myth-of-the-default-constructor

Comment: I've add more specific spring error log. That's not the reason. I try as you suggest, it does not work.

Comment: Great, it works. I don't know there'is such a trick. Now I've learned.