# Swagger UI not displaying nested restcontroller class

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I am working on a project where the lead developer is nesting the RestController classes within other classes.

The swagger configuration is the below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

And the class definitions follow the following format:

```
@Slf4j
public class SomeModule {

    @RestController @Transactional @RequiredArgsConstructor @RequestMapping(value="/a/b/c/something")
    public class Controller {   

        @PostMapping(value="/")
        public HttpEntity<Command> createSomething (@RequestBody CreateSomethingCommand command) {
            ...
        } 
        ...
    }
}
```

When the class `Controller` is taken out of the `SomeModule` class, swagger-ui displays it normally.

However, when it is nested within another class, it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

It turns out that the specific rest controllers are not even accessible as they are nested in another class.

This results in both the @RestController, and also the swagger document generation to silently fail.

The solution for this is to make the nested classes static!

**Static** keyword solves the problem: `public static class Controller {`

### Reference

- [How to create a Spring Bean of a Inner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886526/how-to-create-a-spring-bean-of-a-inner-class#comment15818020_11886527)